# Пропали иконки в браузере Chrome Canary

Tags: google-chrome

Пропали иконки в верхней части браузера Chrome Canary. Переустановка не помогла. В чем может быть проблема и как ее исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась достаточно просто. Помогла перезагрузка ноутбука.

Answer (score 1):

На оф сайте https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/canary.html  сказано что она текстовая версия :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: да это все понятно. уже пользуюсь ей несколько лет, но основной функционал всегда был стабильным, изменения касались больше второстепенных вещей. а здесь просто отрубает функционал на корню.